# Giving equations specific numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and I really would appreciate the help. First I should mention that I use OFFICE 2016.
I used Macro recording to create a macro that copies the selected equation then it inserts a table (one row,two columns)and adjust it to remove borders. After that the macro pastes the copied equation in the first cell and moves to the next cell and insert an empty equation (which the user then inserts the desired number of the equation in it).
It works fine except until it reaches the step where it should paste the copied equation. Every time I run the macro I get

> Run-time error: 6335

and the macro breaks and when I debug it, this is the line that breaks the procedure:

```
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

after debugging when I hit the continue/run button, it completes the job as required.
Below is the macro I use. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub MacroEQNUMBER()
'
' MacroEQNUMBER Macro
'
'
Dim rng As Range
If Selection.Range = "" Then
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    End If
Set rng = Selection.Range
rng.Cut
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
        2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
        .Borders.Enable = False
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Select
    Selection.TypeText Text:="["
    Selection.OMaths.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeText Text:="]"
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells.Width = 80
    Selection.Tables(1).Columns(2).Cells.Width = 350
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Select
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4

End Sub
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsserver/en-US/172e4d1f-bf16-4fd4-9535-49eee80d8b7f/runtime-error-6335-the-action-was-blocked-by-organization-policy?forum=vsto The solution there is to exit all other applications that use the clipboard, most likely because Office Apps all share the same internal clipboard and you're overloading it with the selection.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis. It's not a function call.

Comment: I would consider killing the last two lines also.  This looks like the cursor moving around with no subsequent action.

Comment: You may also be able to change `Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1` to `Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1`

Comment: Kudos on submitting a well-formed question for your first post.

Comment: @braX FYI - although removing the brackets is a good idea, in this case `(wdFormatOriginalFormatting)` and `wdFormatOriginalFormatting` should be identical.  `wdFormatOriginalFormatting` is just a constant (the number 16), so the brackets aren't doing anything - it's like saying `x = (16)` or `x = 16`.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling the problem comes from pasting the equation. Since you're using Selection it's quite possible you're putting the Selection in a table cell *structure*. Word used to allow this, which would "break" the document. In more recent versions it's simply not allowed, which will result in an error...

Rather than try to put bandaids on your recorded code, I've done my best to interpret what is meant (thank you for the excellent description) and convert it to "object code". The SELECTION object isn't ideal because you can never be sure where it is, nor what is meant. Better is to use the underlying object model, usually RANGE objects.

To begin, the Selection is assigned to a Range - now, no matter where the visible selection is in the document, the Range will never change.

Next, I assign the new table to a Table object. From that, I can get the Range of the first cell and work with it (insert text).

I apparently do need a Selection for inserting the OMath, so I position between the square brackets, select and insert that. Finally, the columns are formatted, the cut equation pasted and the selection positioned at the beginning of the first cell (I think that's what you wanted, but I'm not sure about this last).

```
Sub MacroEQNUMBER()
'
' MacroEQNUMBER Macro
'
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As word.Table
Dim cel As word.Cell
Dim rngCell As word.Range

If Selection.Range = "" Then
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    End If
Set rng = Selection.Range
rng.Cut
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
        2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed)
    With tbl
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
        .Borders.Enable = False
    End With

    Set cel = tbl.Cell(1, 1)
    Set rngCell = cel.Range
    rngCell.Text = "[]"
    rngCell.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    rngCell.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1

    rngCell.Select
    rngCell.OMaths.Add Range:=rngCell

    tbl.Columns(1).Cells.width = 80
    tbl.Columns(2).Cells.width = 350

    Set rngCell = tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range
    rngCell.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    rngCell.Characters(rngCell.Characters.Count - 1).Delete
    tbl.Cell(1, 1).Select
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Cindy Meister for your help. The problem is your code is breaking at the paste procedure as well (at this line exactly):     rngCell.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
Is there any way we can go around this error and make the macro work? .... Thank you again for your help.

Comment: That's odd, because it works here without a hitch, on both Word 2010 and 2016. (Although on re-reading your question I see I switched cells, but even turning it around, I still don't see any error message.) What happens if you test on a new document, with nothing else in it but the equation?